# Get a Service context from a normal class

Tags: android-context, accessibilityservice

I have three classes:

```
MyPlugin extends OtherPluginClass extends Service
MyService extends AccesibilityService
LoggerClass implements BaseLoggerClass
```

`MyService` starts when the user authorizes it in Accessibility settings. `MyPlugin` is started and controlled by a different application (tho' I have access to its source code).

The problem is the `LoggerClass` is coordinated by `MyService`, however `LoggerClass` needs the **context** of `MyPlugin` to perform some operations.

I've tried to create a static `sharedContext` variable in `MyPlugin` and populate it in the `onCreate` method, but `LoggerClass` always sees `sharedContext` as null.

What would be the best way for `LoggerClass` to access `MyPlugin`'s **context**?

Comment: Simply put: it can't.  They're completely separate processes.  If you phrase it like: "I need to accomplish this..." we might be able to help.

Comment: At the end I solved it by creating a method

    public static MyPlugin get(){
        return plugin;
    }

And then in the MyPlugin's constructor

    plugin = this;

Is this a safe solution?

Comment: No.  If it's started by a different application, you may no longer be seeing null, but they're going to be separate objects.  A working solution is going to involve some form of cross process communication.  Intents, broadcast receivers, etc.  It may be "safe" as in your not getting null returned from your "sharedContext" but you're not sharing the same object.